# Below two methods return correct results but fails with performance test

Tags: c#, performance, for-loop, iteration

I am writing this method and tried writing it in two ways but this method is failing to pass a performance test.

Method Problem: Write a function that, when passed a list and a target sum, returns, efficiently with respect to time used, two distinct zero-based indices of any two of the numbers, whose sum is equal to the target sum. If there are no two numbers, the function should return null.

For example, FindTwoSum(new List() { 3, 1, 5, 7, 5, 9 }, 10) should return a Tuple containing any of the following pairs of indices:

- 0 and 3 (or 3 and 0) as 3 + 7 = 10
- 1 and 5 (or 5 and 1) as 1 + 9 =10
- 2 and 4 (or 4 and 2) as 5 + 5 = 10

  ```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  class TwoSum
  {
  public static Tuple<int, int> FindTwoSum(IList<int> list, int sum)
  {
      int? item1Index = null;
      int? item2Index = null;

      var len = list.Count;
      int i = 0;
      while (i < len)
      {
          var j = i + 1;
          while (j < len)
          {
              if ((list[i] + list[j]).Equals(sum))
              {
                  item1Index = i;
                  item2Index = j;
                  break;
              }
              j++;
          }
          i++;
      }
      if (item1Index.HasValue && item2Index.HasValue)
          return new Tuple<int, int>(item1Index.Value, item2Index.Value);

      return null;
  }

  public static Tuple<int, int> FindTwoSum2(IList<int> list, int sum)
  {
      int? item1Index = null;
      int? item2Index = null;


      var result = (from list1 in list.Select((i,idx)=> new { item= i, index = idx})
                    from list2 in list.Select((i, idx) => new { item = i, index = idx })
                    select new
                    {
                        ListOneItem = list1.item,
                        ListOneItemIndex = list1.index,
                        ListTwoItem = list2.item,
                        ListTwoItemIndex = list2.index
                    }).Where(c => c.ListOneItemIndex != c.ListTwoItemIndex 
                                  && (c.ListOneItem + c.ListTwoItem).Equals(sum))

                      .FirstOrDefault();
      if (result != null)
          return new Tuple<int, int>(result.ListOneItemIndex, result.ListTwoItemIndex);
      return null;       
  }

  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
      Tuple<int, int> indices = FindTwoSum(new List<int>() { 3, 1, 5, 7, 5, 9 }, 10);
      if (indices != null)
      {
          Console.WriteLine(indices.Item1 + " " + indices.Item2);
      }
  }  
  }
  ```

Comment: What 'performance test' is it failing?

Comment: When large number of items are passed to this method. It times out.

Comment: Test for : result.Count() > 0 instead of null.

Comment: 'Times out'  - the code has no timing mechanism.   What are you using to do the timing?   Is there some test framework you are using?   Is it just 'taking a long time to finish' ?

Comment: Sounds like an online coding test to me. Your first method should return as soon as it finds a solution, not try every single combination.

Comment: @Neil You got it right, it just takes too long to finish when list items are too large.

Comment: Instead of break you should return otherwise, the code is evaluating all combination. Also, you can follow the approach mentioned in [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/solution/) link to write the hash based approach which works in one pass (in one while loop)

Comment: @DavidG can you plz pin-point exactly which method line is iterating till the end?

Comment: @jNet Your code tries every single combination of numbers which is very computationally intensive. You just need to return when you find the first match. Like this for example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/irPmRN

Comment: @user1672994 you are right. let me try it.

Comment: @DavidG Thank you for the efforts. let me try.

Comment: The hashtable O(N) solution [is detailed here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-an-array-a-and-a-number-x-check-for-pair-in-a-with-sum-as-x/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `break` from inner `while` you should `return` otherwise, the code is evaluating all combination via outer `while` loop.

Also, you can follow the below optimal approach which uses dictionary based approach to evaluate the sum in one pass (in one while loop).

Details about code:

- The below program supports fast look up by using `Dictionary`.
- The list is iterated and inserts elements into the Dictionary, It also look back to check if current element's complement already exists in the Dictionary. I
- The program checks if each element's complement (target - nums[i]) exists in the `Dictionary`. If it exists, then that's the solution and return it immediately.

  ```
  public static Tuple<int, int> FindTwoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
    Dictionary<int, int> hashData = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    for (int index = 0; index < nums.Length; index++)
    {
      int remainingTarget = target - nums[index];
      if (hashData.ContainsKey(remainingTarget))
      {
          return new Tuple<int, int>(hashData[remainingTarget], index);
      }
      else
      {
          if (!hashData.ContainsKey(nums[index]))
          {
              hashData.Add(nums[index], index);
          }
       }
   }

    return null;
  }
  ```

Since each element of list is traversed only once that's why Time Complexity of this program is `O(n)`. Each look up in the table costs only O(1)O(1) time.

Comment: Thank you,  this solution has passed my performance test.  FYI, plz fix minor bug in this code so that I can mark this as an answer. thanks

Comment: @jNet - what is the minor bug?

Comment: It may be useful to describe how this works: Given target total = T: For each number N, if [N-T] exists then we have two numbers that add to T, namely N and N-T. We determine if [N-T] exists by looking it up in a hash table, which is what makes this algorithm O(N) complexity. We can add numbers to the hash table as we iterate all the numbers, hence just one loop.

Comment: @MatthewWatson - sure. let me add the description.